# Excel VBA to clear a range of rows on multiple sheets based on the last used row for that sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I use for keeping and updating the details of different products for a project. All the products are entered onto the "Master Sheet" and then transferred onto the Stage specific Sheets(eg. "Stage 1 Sheet"). I want to be able to update any details on the Master Sheet and then run a macro which clears the Stage Sheets and re-transfers the products to the specific Stage Sheet.
I have been able to get it to transfer the products to the correct Stage Sheet based on the Stage column. However I can't find a way that updates the Stage Sheets when a detail on a product on the Master Sheet is changed, deleted or added. 
Here is the Macro I have written for transferring the data to the correct Stage Sheets:

```
Sub Stages()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 10 To LR
        If Range("BF" & i).Value = "1" Then Rows(i).Copy      Destination:=Sheets("Stage 1 Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If Range("BF" & i).Value = "2" Then Rows(i).Copy      Destination:=Sheets("Stage 2 Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
     Next i
End Sub
```

The problem I keep hitting is that for each stage there will be a different number of Products and possibly none at all.
Currently I have only 2 Stage Sheets but will be needing to allow for having 22 of them. 
There is one constant on every Stage Sheet. It is that the Products get entered into Row 10 and down.
Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if you have any queries or need further information.

Comment: Qualify that `Rows.Count` part, so `Destination:=Sheets("Stage 1 Sheet").Range("A" & Sheets("Stage 1 Sheet").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`, and same for your "Stage 2 Sheet"  and see if that helps.  Also, without qualifying with a sheet, `Range()` and `Rows.Count` will run on whatever your ActiveSheet is, which may or may not be what you want/expect.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne for your help. I want to add to the macro above so that it ensures that from row 10 down is cleared of data so that when this macro is run again for any updates it doesn't enter the same data twice. However there is data in below where the products go which I don't want deleted. Is there a way to determine the last used row working down from row 10?

Comment: @BruceWayne would it be possible to delete the entire product line on the Stage Sheets and then re-insert the entire row with the updated data from the Master Sheet? I have been trying to do that but its not working.

Comment: @BruceWayne here is the code I have tried.     ' Sub Stages()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, s As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For s = 1 To 2
    Sheets("Stage " & s & " Sheet").Range(Sheets("Stage " & s & " Sheet").Cells("A10),Sheets("Stage " & s & " Sheet")Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Delete

For i = 10 To LR
    If Range("BF" & i).Value = "1" Then Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Stage 1 Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '
    Etc As per last code.